# How to set/get a value in a multilevel dictionary?

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary called `stuff`, structured like this:

```
 {
    "ThingStats" : { "Thing1" : { "stat1" : 12,
                                  "stat2" : 21 } ,
                     "Thing2" : { "stat1" : 4,
                                  "stat2" : 15 }
              } ,

    "OtherStuff" : {...}
 }
```

In addition to `ThingStats` it can have other dictionaries at that first level.

Using subscripting it's easy to get `Thing1's` `stat1` like this:

```
stat1 = stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing1"][@"stat1"];
```

and set it like this:

```
stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing1"][@"stat1"] = @13;
```

This all works great when the keys exist.

**First question**: If the `ThingStats` dictionary doesn't exist in `stuff` yet, what is the best way to get the structure of `ThingStats` started with the first entry? For example if I only have the values for `stat1` and `stat2` for `Thing1` what is the easiest way to end up with the `stuff` dictionary shown below from an empty `stuff` dictionary? Assume that `stuff` won't be nil.

```
 { "ThingStats" : { "Thing1" : { "stat1" : 12, "stat2" : 21 } } }
```

**Second question**: Later, when I get the values for `stat1` and `stat2` for `Thing2` what is the best way to add those values to end up with this structure:

```
 {
    "ThingStats" : { "Thing1" : { "stat1" : 12,
                                  "stat2" : 21 } ,
                     "Thing2" : { "stat1" : 4,
                                  "stat2" : 15 }
                   }
 }
```

**Third question**: If I want to use the subscripting technique above to set a new value for a stat do I have to do something like this first to ensure that the keys exist all the way to the value:

```
if (stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing1"][@"stat1"]) {
    stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing1"][@"stat1"] = newValue;
} else {
    // add the new stat some other way
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "what is the best way to add that to end up with this:"?

Comment: It's just objects -- dictionaries and arrays.  The thing to remember is that a dictionary/array created with literal expressions is immutable, and if you want to modify a dictionary/array it must be mutable.

Comment: If I get you, create a new dictionary with `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`.  Add elements to it using `myDict[@"keyValue"] = elementValue;`.  Just keep doing that until the structure is done.

Comment: (Hint:  You have 5 dictionaries in the the above structure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your on the right track. Your question 3 answers your first question. For your first question you could use:

```
//Setup
NSMutableDictionary *stuff = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

if (!stuff[@"ThingStats"]) {
    stuff[@"ThingStats"] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing1"] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing2"] = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
}

//Use

stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing1"][@"stat1"] = @12;
stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing1"][@"stat2"] = @21;
stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing2"][@"stat1"] = @4;
stuff[@"ThingStats"][@"Thing2"][@"stat2"] = @15;
```